# Compare arrays and add missing key value to array

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

First

```
array (size=6)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '25-34' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '45' (length=2)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '55-64' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '1' (length=1)
 2 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '13-17' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '3' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '35-44' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '11' (length=2)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '18-24' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '46' (length=2)
5 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '45-54' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Second:

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '65+' (length=3)
  'Count' => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '13-17' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '4' (length=1)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '35-44' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '3' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '25-34' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '11' (length=2)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  'Age' => string '18-24' (length=5)
  'Count' => string '20 |' (length=4)
```

Now what here I am getting is that First array size is larger than Second one, so I need a solution for making the small size array similar to larger size array.

With same keys, and add value zero to new added keys value.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by similar here.  Your second array is missing one value from the first array.  You could get at that with array_diff();

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge( $firstArray, $secondArray );`

Please see [array_merge();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)